# Why memory is not allocated to class when we create pointer type object?

Tags: c++, object

I am little bit curious about that why memory is not allocated to a class or structure when we create pointer type object ?

For example :-

```
class A
{
    public:

    void show()
    {
        cout<<" show function "<<endl;  
    }

};
int main()
{
A *a;
a->show();
   return 0;
};
```

Comment: Pointers are used for more than just allocating things on the free store. Why should I have to delete some random object I never created if I'm using a raw pointer for something a smart pointer can't/shouldn't do?

Comment: The question can be turned back and we could ask, "Why do you need to create a pointer when you could create an object?"

Comment: when we doing work with linked list we creates some object of struct that are pointer type like *head but i am always thinking about that when we create object variable type then memory will allocate to struct but when we create pointer type then memory will not create but why ?

Comment: You can use pointers to point to hardware registers, which are not in the memory area of your program.

Answer (score 10):

Because pointers and memory allocation are a priori completely unrelated. In fact, in modern C++ it’s downright *bad* to use pointers to point to manually allocated memory directly.

In most cases, pointers point to *existing* objects – that’s their purpose: to provide [indirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). To reiterate: this is completely unrelated to memory allocation.

If you want to directly have an object you don’t need a pointer: just declare the object as-is (= by value):

```
A a;
a.show();
```

Comment: ok and so in this case when you create a variable compiler implicitly using new to allocate memory am I right ?

Comment: No. No `new` is being used in any conventional sense. Memory allocation is a bit less straightforward than that.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
A *a;
a->show();
```

just ***declares*** a pointer of type `A*`. Pointer alone is nothing but a variable that holds an address of some memory in it, i.e. it just points somewhere, nothing else. Pointer of type `A*` means that it points to memory, where an instance of type `A` is *expected* to be found.

`a->show();` then just relies on this "expectation", but in fact it just uses uninitialized pointer, which results in *undefined behavior*.

---

This could be either solved by dynamically creating an instance of `A`:

```
A *a = new A();
a->show();
```

(which however gives you unpleasant responsibility for cleaning up this memory by calling `delete a;`) or even better: using an object with automatic storage duration instead:

```
A a;
a.show();
```

In the second case, an instance of type `A` is created automatically and its lifetime is tied to the scope, in which it has been created. Once the execution leaves this scope, `a` is destructed and memory is freed. All of that is taken care of, without you worrying about it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Allocating a pointer does not equate to allocating an object. You need to use `new` and instantiate an object on the heap, or create the object on the stack:

```
A* a = new A();
// Or
A a;
A* aPntr = &a;
```

Comment: Allocating a pointer does not equate to allocating an object.

actually that's my question why it is not equate ?

Comment: @VikasVerma: Because when you allocate a pointer in C++, you are really only allocating an integer (32 or 64 bit depending on architecture). To allocate an object, you have to explicitly say so. i.e. the `new` keyword to allocate on the heap, or instantiating on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer is not an object, it’s just a link that *points* somewhere. The reason to use them is that you can dynamically change what they’re pointing to.

```
A a;
A b;
A *pA;

{
    bool condition;
    // set condition here according to user input, a file or anything else...

    if(condition)
        pA = &a;
    else
        pA = &b;
}
```

Now I don’t have to take care about condition, it even doesn’t have to exist anymore and still I can profit from the choice made above.

```
pA->show();
```

---

Or I can use pointer to iterate over an array:

```
A array[10];
for(A* pA = array; pA < array+10; pA++)
{
    pA->show();
}
```

(Note I used the original declaration of `class A` in both examples altough more meaningful it would be if each object of class `A` contained its specific information.)

Answer (score 2):

There may not be one single reason for `A *a;` not to allocate an instance of `A`. It would be at odds with how C++ is designed. I would be somewhat surprised if Stroustrup considered it for long enough to identify a definitive reason not to do it.

A few different ways to look at it:

1. You didn't ask for an object of type `A`, so you don't get one. That's how C and C++ work.
2. A pointer object is an object that holds an address. You may as well ask why stationary manufacturers don't build a house when they manufacture an envelope, as ask why C++ doesn't allocate an object to be pointed at when you define a pointer.
3. There are many ways to allocate memory. Supposing that memory was going to be allocated, which one would you like? You could argue that in C++ `new` would be a sensible default for class types, but then it would probably be quite confusing either if `char *c;` called `new char` (because the behavior would be different from C) or if `char *c;` didn't allocate memory at all (because the behavior would be different from `char *A;`.
4. How and when would the memory be freed? If it's allocated with `new` then someone is going to have to call `delete`. It's much easier to keep things straight if each `delete` corresponds to a `new`, rather than each `delete` corresponding either to `new` or to defining a pointer with implicit memory allocation.
5. A pointer can be the location of an object, but it isn't always (sometimes it's null, sometimes it's off-the-end of an array). The object can be dynamically allocated but doesn't have to be. It would be very unhelpful of the language to make a pointer point to an object in cases where you don't need it. Therefore the language gives you the option not to allocate memory when defining a pointer. If you don't want that, then you should initialize the pointer with the result of a call to the memory-allocation mechanism of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You just create a pointer *a, but not allocate memory for it.

you should use A *a = new A();

Comment: I know that I was just create a pointer but it I can also say in this case A a; I just create a variable then now why memory is allocated to class ?

Comment: when you use A a, actually you call the construct function which will allocate memory for object. But if you use A *a, it just means you create a pointer, the pointers' type is A.